# How to update HTML element class after it's clicked in VueJS?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `VueJS 2.3.0`, and now I need to update `HTML` element's class after it's clicked.

I have this template code:

```
<template id="model-template">
    <span>
        <button v-on:click="activate" >{{ model.fu }} month</button>
    </span>
</template>
```

I just checked the VueJS official documentation about `:class` solution, but I'm confused...

If I use jQuery, then I code this to do what I want to do:

```
$('button').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('button').removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

UPDATE: this is find all buttons, remove 'clicked' class from each button elements, and add 'clicked' class to only that one what the user is clicked.

How can I do same thing in VueJS?

Comment: You want to remove the clicked class from all other buttons in your component and then add it to the button that was clicked?

Comment: @BertEvans: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

`activeClass` is a property in your vue instance.The below syntax means the presence of the `active` class will be determined by the truthiness of the data property activeClass. i.e if `activeClass = true` then class `active` will be added and if `activeClass = false` it will be removed from the button.

```
<template id="model-template">
    <span>
        <button v-bind:class="{active : activeClass}" >{{ model.fu }} month</button>
    </span>
</template>
```

Once you understand and implement it will be even more simple then jquery.

jsfiddle if you want to see it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/riazxrazor/5jfnwav4/4/

Comment: Looking good, but this solution set true / false only that one copy of button element. I want to set all of buttons to false, and only that one true what the user clicked.

Comment: i wasn't able to achieve in a simple way had to hack a little but i managed to do it, u can have a look.
https://jsfiddle.net/riazxrazor/5jfnwav4/7/